# File name too long error creating a json file in bash

Tags: json, bash

I am trying to create a json file with a bash script I created. The script creates the file, but the file is empty.

When it runs, I get this error: `File name too long`

And the file has no contents, it's completely empty:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 tdunphy tdunphy 0 Jan 25 09:45 pol-aws-secrets-manager-aws-test-user-one.json
```

I suspect that the file name is not the problem. I think that the contents of the file may be too long. Is there a limit on how much you can echo into a text file using bash?

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
aws_user_name=tim
aws_kms_key_arn=arn
create_secrets_manager_policy() {

output_dir="../json/iam"
ofile="$output_dir"/pol-aws-secrets-manager-"$aws_user_name".json

#### BEGIN JSON
 echo
  "{
    \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",
    \"Statement\": [{
        \"Effect\": \"Allow\",
        \"Action\": [
          \"secretsmanager:ListSecrets\",
          \"secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword\"
        ],
        \"Resource\": \"*\"
      },
      {
        \"Effect\": \"Allow\",
        \"Action\": [
          \"kms:Decrypt\"
        ],
        \"Resource\": \"$aws_kms_key_arn\"
      },
      {
        \"Effect\": \"Allow\",
        \"Action\": [
          \"kms:List*\"
        ],
        \"Resource\": \"*\"
      },
      {
        \"Effect\": \"Allow\",
        \"Action\": [
          \"secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy\",
          \"secretsmanager:GetSecretValue\",
          \"secretsmanager:DescribeSecret\",
          \"secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds\"
        ],
        \"Resource\": \"*\",
        \"Condition\": {
          \"ForAnyValue:StringEquals\": {
            \"secretsmanager:ResourceTag/Name\": \"$aws_user_name\"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }"  > "$ofile"

  ######## END JSON     

}
```

Comment: Use a tool like `jq` to generate parameterized JSON, rather than relying on variable interpolation.

Comment: Can you point me to the docs on how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the string you want echoed starts on a separate line from the `echo` command. That means it'll echo nothing, then try to run the string itself as a command -- and it's too long to be a command, so you get the "File name too long" error. (If the error message seems strange, note that commands actually *are* filenames.)

Direct solution: either start the string on the same line as `echo`, or put an escape (backslash) at the end of the `echo` line to continue it on the next line.

Alternate solution: I'd actually do this with a here-document, instead of using `echo` with a long string. The biggest difference is that you don't need to escape the double-quotes in the string this way. You would need to escape any "$" characters you didn't want interpreted as variable substitutions, and any backslash characters that should be literal... but I don't see any of either of those in your string. So it's look something like this:

```
cat >"$ofile" <EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
...
           "secretsmanager:ResourceTag/Name": "$aws_user_name"
         }
       }
     }
   ]
}
EOF
```

Other alternate solution: it's really better to construct json using a tool like `jq` that handles json syntax properly. IMO it's ok to skip that in this case, because the strings being interpolated shouldn't contain anything that'd need special treatment. But this is a shortcut, not really the *right* way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `echo` is the first and only token on its line, so it is parsed as a command, which has an associated builtin which is executed without parameters. Without any parameters, `echo` will just output a linefeed.

Then the next line contains a string spanning on multiple lines, which is the first token of these lines. Once again it is parsed as a command; it has no associated builtin, so it is searched as an executable file in the `$PATH`, which probably is what fails here.

Remove the linefeed between the `echo` and the text it's supposed to echo, or escape it with `\` and this should be working.